# stackoverflow profile suddenly showing me as a new user

Tags: support, profile-page

I logged in to my stackoverflow profile after some 10 days and found this page:

[image]

This shows me as first time I am visiting this site(a new user). I had so many questions, answers and badges in associated with this profile. Also I earned some 600 repo. When I click on achievement link, it shows previous badges(Notable question etc.) earned on stackoverflow.

Is my profile deleted as part of moderation? Can I get my questions/Answers back?

Comment: Is this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331538/find-the-processor-speed-of-an-android-device-in-mhz - the "Notable Question" in the screen shot above? If that's the case then it does look like your account was deleted.

Comment: @ChrisF Yes....

Comment: @ChrisF but why is it deleted?

Comment: Another pointer from your dropdown: [How to implement horizontal swipe inside a fragment?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16032596), same account.

Comment: @JackDaniels - do you really want to make that information public? (Hint: I wouldn't).

Comment: @ChrisF This account I was using from more than 2 years and from past 2 months I didn't post anything

Comment: You'll need to [contact us](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) as your account was removed for purposes of moderation. I'm not inclined to discuss the details of the action taken publicly, this is best handled via email.